# Is there an equivalent in Java for fieldset (HTML)?

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt

Is there an element in Java (i.e. Swing/AWT or SWT) that is equivalent to the HTML element `fieldset`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a Panel, create a titled border and you will be able to put inside all your field components.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JLabel("foo"));
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("bar"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at `javax.swing.border.TitledBorder`. You can set them on panels and are similar in appearance to HTML fieldsets.

```
Border titleBorder = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED), "Fieldset");
```

You could then add the border to your panel using the `setBorder()` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SWT than I think that `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group` is what you are looking for. It is a `Composite` (a block in HTML analogy) and it looks like a fieldset in HTML.

I can't speak for AWT and SWING however.