# What kind of box is this in java?

Tags: java, jframe

[image: bottom box]

On the bottom of the container where it says Statistic, what kind of box is that. I am using JFrame and would like to duplicate that.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820724/1065197

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container you're seeing is a `JPanel`. Followed by adding a border to it. You can add a border with text, by doing.

```
// panel is a JPanel
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
```

You can read more about it on the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) there is even a lot of examples, showing the various borders, etc.

There is even a ["BorderDemo.java"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/BorderDemoProject/src/components/BorderDemo.java) you can get from the Java Docs.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html). It provides means for visually structuring elements into box-like containers. You can find more information on how to effectively use and style them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

EDIT: Since you seem to be more interested in the style of the border than the name of the component being used in the example above here's a snippet using the border style on a panel.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanelTestDrive{
        public static void main(String [] args){
             JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Panel Test Drive");
             myFrame.setSize(800,600);
             JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
             myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel Title"));
             myFrame.add(myPanel);
             myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: So if I make a new JPanel, it will put the outline around the "Number of correct answers" and "Number of wrong answers" ?

Comment: why the downvote? isn't it a jpanel? looks like a jpanel for me

Comment: @Leo if you think this answer is right, then upvote it instead of posting a comment :)

Comment: It's right that it is a `JPanel` but a `TitledBorder` can be used on other `Component`... it doesn't really answer the question.